# convert 8.1 pro 64 bits to windows 10 is this a right choice to develop for UWP applications

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I need your help please,I want to develop for UWP with windows 10(I tried to install windows 10 as a VMWare workstation virtual machine but I never have found the right ISO file(my processor supports virtual machines of 32 bits),so I need to convert my windows 8.1 pro 64 bits to windows 10

My question is, will this installation cause any errors:

This is my system configuration

Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @2.13Ghz 2.13Ghz

RAM: 4.00 Gb(3.80Gb used)

OS: 64bits,processor x64 Windows 8.1 Professional

thanks for help

Comment: The system requirements for Windows 10 are identical to those of Windows 8.1.  You can upgrade to Windows 10 through Windows Update or download the Media Creation Tool and do it that way.

Comment: Just a *caveat*: image your OS disk so you can go back if there are issues, such as the recent spate of Windows 10 upgrade *uninstalling* existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to develop Windows 10 apps on Windows 8 (and Windows 7) machines, it requires a separate Windows 10 device if you wish to debug. If your goal is to write a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, that is to say a Windows app, then upgrading to Windows 10 is the right thing to do for the sake of your own time and headache. Not to mention, Windows 10 is pretty nice. Remember, Windows 10 update 1 has been released, so be sure to upgrade one up have updated. Also, Visual Studio 2015 now has Update 1 which should be publically available in just a few days - so once you have installed Visual Studio 2015, be sure and update so you are writing Windows apps that target the UWP version 10.0.10586. I hope this helps.

Since you are just getting started, I will also point you to http://aka.ms/template10

As for system requirements. The system requirements for Windows 7 are less than that of Windows Vista. The system requirements for Windows 8 are less than that of Windows 7. And, the system requirements for Windows 10 are less than that of Windows 8. Amazing stuff, huh?